# Android WebView - Custom font from assets not loaded in HTML page

Tags: android, html, css, webview, custom-font

My Android app loads an HTML file into a WebView.
It's made of normal text and some icons. These are from the material icons set from Google.

Here's the working HTML file (icons correctly displayed):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML >
<HEAD>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<BODY style="text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-word;margin-left:4px;width:95%;max-width:95%;word-wrap: break-word;" >
Normal text here
<br/>
<i class="material-icons" >home</i>
<br/>
    Normal text here      
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Instead this does not work (the label of the icon is displayed as text):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML >
<HEAD>
<meta charset="UTF-8">          
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">      
</head>
<BODY style="text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-word;margin-left:4px;width:95%;max-width:95%;word-wrap: break-word;" >
<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: material-icons-font;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/materialiconsregular.ttf\");} material-icons {font-family:material-icons-font;}</style>
Normal text here
<br/>
<i class="material-icons" >home</i>
<br/>
Normal text here      
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am interested in the second one. But I do not understand why it does not work, as it is from SO answers.

materialiconsregular.ttf is the font file. It is placed in assets but eventually I would like to use the one I put in res/font folder with this fonts.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<font
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="400"
    app:font="@font/materialiconsregular"
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/materialiconsregular"
    />

</font-family>
```

The font in resources is used in other parts of the application and it works.

The font file was renamed: the original name was MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf, although I do not think it causes any problem.

The instruction in Java code is:

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", readTextFromResource(this, R.raw.instructions),"text/html","utf-8","");
```

or

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", readTextFromResource(this, R.raw.instructions),"text/html","utf-8","");
```

What's wrong in my code?